# Detectar quando usuário aperta ENTER

Tags: jquery

Tenho um código jQuery que detecta quando a tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> é pressionada, porém o evento também é chamado quando utilizo <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, por exemplo.

Como faço pra detectar apenas o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>? A intenção é enviar o formulário apenas quando a tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for pressionada, deixando o <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> para quebra de linha.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.comment-textarea', function(event) {   
    if (event.which == 13) {
        console.log('ENTER');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Faz assim, vc verificar se o shift está apertado.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.comment-textarea', function(event) {   
    if (event.which == 13) {
         if(event.shiftKey){
             console.log('Quebra de linha');
         }else{
             console.log('ENTER');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Ricardo!